# Nginx cors setting not working in docker container

Tags: angularjs, docker, nginx, nginx-location, nginx-reverse-proxy

I'm trying to deploy frontend (angular ) and backend (.net core) through docker compose on linux server. I have created two docker files present in respective file. Here is my **docker.compos.yml** file.

```
version: '3.4 
  volumes: 
   data:

services:
  api:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Backend/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "5000:80"
    depends_on:
      - db
  web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Frontend/Dockerfile
    ports:
     - "80:80"
    depends_on:
      - api
  db:
    image: postgres:latest
    volumes: 
     - data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: "postgres"
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: "docker_Password"
      POSTGRES_DB: "database_name"
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
```

I'm using nginx image for serving front end build. Here is the **default.conf** file with basic settings.

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;
    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
    }
}
```

With above configuration,I ran **docker-compose up --build** and I'm able to see my login page (as port 80 is exposed so my url is my server ip). But when I try to login it sends an ajax request to my api service which is running on port 5000, and I got cross origin error as my frontend which is running on port 80 and trying to access a service which is running on port 5000. 
I wanted to do something that all my request starting with  api path (here in my case it is **{server_ip}/api/login**) should redirect to api service. Is there anything in nginx which is helpful in redirecting request?

I also tried with adding following lines in location block of **default.conf**, but no success.

> add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'  '*';
>
> add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods'  'GET, POST, OPTIONS'

;

Answer (score 3):

Try adding the following to nginx configuration so it forwards all `/api/login` requests to http://api:5000/.

```
location /api/login {
  proxy_pass http://api:5000;
}
```

You can also use [rewrite](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html) to make nginx call your API server without the `/api/login` prefix.

```
location /api/login {
  rewrite ^/api/login/(.*) /$1 break;
  proxy_pass http://api:5000;
}
```

The CORS headers probably didn't work because nginx was returning them, but you needed your API server to return them.

Comment: @kichick, tried the above solution, but it didn't work. I got this error as it was before.
`Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource`

Comment: Did you also update your JavaScript to access `/api/login` on port 80? It should use CORS if it's on the exact same origin.

Comment: I have fixed it today. I removed port(5000 in this case) from proxy pass nginx configuration. Thanks @kichik